# How to correct bind SelectListItem with a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, nullreferenceexception, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlistitem

I have issue with correct bind SelectListItem with a view.

**ItemController.cs**

```
 public ActionResult SelectCondition()
        {

            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "New", Value = "0", Selected=true });

            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Old", Value = "1" });

            var model = new Item
            {
                ItemCondition = items
            };

            return View();

        }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectCondition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.ItemCondition)
```

**Item.cs**

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ItemCondition { get; set; }
```

Now I have **NullReferenceException** and underlined this line in **Create.cshtml**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it very suspicious for Visual Studio that `var model` is declared but never used?

Pass the model to the view. `return View(model)`.

And general suggestion: Work with strongly typed views...

Comment: i pass the model to the view, but still have same problem - NullReferenceException :(

Comment: Make `ItemConditiion` property in `Item` class the respective type, then tell your View that your model is of type `Item` and remove the cast.